# How to start jetty in debug mode from ant

Tags: java, debugging, jetty, embedded-jetty

How can I start embedded jetty server in debug mode from ant? Here is my build.xml file:

```
<target name="jettyRun">
    <delete dir="jetty-temp" quiet="true" />
    <jetty tempDirectory="jetty-temp">
        <webApp name="${application.name}" warfile="${fileToDeploy}" contextpath="/${application.name}"/>
        <webApp name="${application.name}resources" warfile="${resourcesToDeploy}" contextpath="/${application.name}resources"/>
    </jetty>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should help you
http://swik.net/Peter-Thomas/Incremental+Operations/How+to+start+and+stop+Jetty+from+Ant/mut2

Basically you start the jetty server like this

```
<java jar="${jetty.home}/start.jar" fork="true" dir="${jetty.home}">
    <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Xdebug"/>
 </Java>
```

Hope this helps.